# Displaying Date programmatically in C1Calendar, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How does one display a date on the C1Calendar using code from the aspx.cs page? The goal is so that the user can see a programmed date on the calendar automatically without having to select the date they want to choose.

For example i'm trying to make it display a date in 2011:

**aspx page:**

```
<cc2:C1Calendar ClientIDMode="Static" ID="clStartDate" runat="server" Height="180px" Width="230px" UseEmbeddedVisualStyles="True"
                                            VisualStyle="Office2007Silver">
</cc2:C1Calendar>
```

**aspx.cs page:**

```
clStartDate.SelectedDateTime = new DateTime(2011, 8, 1);
```

also tried this:

```
clStartDate.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2011, 8, 1);
```

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: Based on an example on their site, try `clStartDate.SelectedDates = new []{DateTime(2011, 8, 1)};`

[Programatically Set SelectedDates](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/c1calendar-programmatically-set-selecteddates/)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm having no luck, but i appreciate your research.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on this [documentation](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1schedulerSL/C1.WPF.Schedule.4~C1.WPF.Schedule.C1Calendar~Today.html) you can set the current date with the #Today() method.

Comment: Is it possible to display a date other than today's date?